# Calling a function within a variable declaration

Tags: javascript

In my lifelong quest to write my entire code on a single line, and give all the psychopathic maintainers nightmares, I ask the following question:

Is there any way I can instantiate an object, assign it to a variable, and call a function on the instantiation on the same line?

Eg I have:

```
var abc=new window();
window.show()
```

But i want something along the lines of...

```
(var abc= new window).show()
```

Comment: Have you ever seen minified JavaScript? Entire frameworks can be only one "line" of code.

Comment: Don't know why this got downvoted. With a bit of a brain you can realize that this question obviously is about one *statement*, regardless of the number of lines.

Comment: @Pumbaa80 From the OP: "to write my entire code on a single line","on the same line".

Comment: not a good coding practice to do this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the essence of qour question is: Can you use `var` inside an expression?

The answer is No. A `var` statement is, well, a statement, and not an expression. The contents of parentheses however need to be expressions.

If you're interested in the technical details, see http://ecma262-5.com/ELS5_HTML_with_CorrectionNotes.htm#AnnexA, A.3 and A.4

---

Edit: You can however use

```
var abc;
(abc = new window()).show();
```

...which is pretty pointless here I guess.

Answer (score 1):

Sure.  Use an anonymous function to allow you to embed statements inside your expression thus:

```
var abc = (function (abc) { return abc.show(), abc }(new window));
```

Answer (score 0):

How about?

```
var abc=new window();abc.show();
```

Or in one statement

```
new window().show();
```

Or using eval()

```
eval("var abc=new window();abc.show();")
```

Comment: Using semicolons defeats the purpose of sticking it on a single line. ( Eg: thats 2 statements instead of 1 )

Comment: Updated it to be one statement.

Comment: That use of `eval` won't work in ES5 strict mode or ES.next since strict mode removes the ability of `eval` to introduce new local variables and ES.next builds on strict mode.